# Can't delete a folder because it's too deep

Tags: windows-8

I have no idea how this happened, but I have a folder with so many sub folders that I can't delete the root folder. I have been googling this for about 2 hours and I've tried many things, nothing is working.

[image]

I've tried a few 3rd party tools, but no luck. I also can't map a drive to anyplace inside this folder. It tells me the path is not valid.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this problem on my job. I ended up mapping a Drive with three or four folders. Just enough to shorten the path a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shorten the names of the folders the undeletable folder resides in so the whole path has a maximum of around 250 Charakters. Then you should be able to delete it.

Example:

If the last folder can not be delted:

C:\folder1xxxxxxxx\folder2xxxxxx\folder3xxxxx\lastfolder

Now you should be able to delete it:

C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\lastfolder

Comment: Geepers!  That was a LOT of folder renaming.  But that did the trick

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Sure thing would you mind accepting my answer if it gave you the solution?

Comment: have to wait for it to allow me to, but yes I will